# VPN not disconnected in Sleep Mode

Tags: windows-10, vpn, sleep, power-management

I have weird issue of a user whose VPN does not disconnected when the PC goes into sleep mode. 
Things I have done:

- I have checked the power settings to make sure the power button is set to sleep when pressed.
- I have changed the USB adapter to which all the monitors, network cable and surface are connected.
- I have checked the network adapter settings in Device Manager.

Nothing seems to work. The user shows connected in Task Manager even after sleep mode is activated.

What am I missing? The user is using a Surface Windows 10 which is connected to 3 other monitors.

Comment: Are you sure the VPN client is not simply restoring the connection after sleep? Do you want to disable this behavior? Which VPN client/type are you using?

Comment: I am not sure if the VPN is restoring the connection but the user did tell me that she disconnects the VPN connection before leaving. But shouldn't the sleep mode be turning off all the network connections by default ? Yes, I want to disable this behavior. I use Sonic Wall Net extender 9.0.274

Comment: The user said they’re disconnecting the VPN and it automatically reconnects? Unlikely. Are you sure it’s not set to be always on or whatever? I am not familiar with NetExtender.

Comment: I know it's unlikely that if the user disconnects the vpn manually, it will reconnect automatically. But I am sure that when the power button is hit to sleep the vpn does not disconnect. I am pretty sure that there are no option to keep VPN always turned on in NetExtender.

Comment: lots of VPN services have `auto connect` feature even if you logout or put it to sleep the moment you login to your desktop the connection sets VPN on. I'm not familiar with your VPN service but you can look for a setting alike.